# cake php import library with many php files which include other files

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have some php library with this structure:

```
folder1
    some_php_files.php
folder2
    some_php_files.php
folder3
    some_php_files.php
```

Each file from each folder uses somthing like this `include_once(../folder2/some_file.php)`

Now I put all three folders in my app/lib directory so I have app/lib/folder1, app/lib/folder2 ...

And I am using in my controller: `App::import('Lib', 'folder1/main_php_file');` and it wroks that it includes this file but then there is a problem with those include directives as the working directory during include is 'app/webroot'.

How I can fix this? Is there any option to get the current file directory (in lib php files) to include other files relative to it?

Answer (score 1):

okay I made it using `include_once(__DIR__.'/../path');`